# How to do select encrypt in workbench

Tags: mysql, select, passwords, workbench

I am using Workbench for Mac
When I trying to do select encrypt, I have no result in the field. If I copy the field I obtain tree dots "..."

I try the same thing with Query Browser and I have a result.

How to display this in workbench ?

```
select encrypt("mypassword")
```

Comment: Beware that 99.999999% of the time (especially with new users), encryption in the database layer does not solve the problems that you think it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ENCRYPT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/encryption-functions.html#function_encrypt) returns a binary string.

By default, MySQL Workbench does not display binary strings (to avoid accidental misinterpretation); however it is possible to display binary string values in output grids: View > Edit > Preferences > SQL Editor > Treat `BINARY/VARBINARY` as nonbinary character string.

Alternatively, transcode the result to a non-binary string:

```
SELECT CONVERT(ENCRYPT('test') USING utf8)
```

Or encode it in a suitable fashion:

```
SELECT HEX(ENCRYPT('test'))
```